# TypeError: undefined is not an object axios.get

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a react native app with a lot of http requests.

To improve the organization of the code, distribute the requests in different files:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq4bY.png]

I'm creating the axios instance in the index.js file:

```
    import Config from "react-native-config";
    import axios from "axios";

    const options = {
        baseURL: Config.BASE_URL + "/api/v4",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        timeout: 5000,
        timeoutErrorMessage: "Tempo de resposta excedido",
    };

    export const apiV4 = axios.create(options);
```

And in User.js for example, i have:

```
    import { apiV4 } from ".";
    import { UserMapper } from "./Mappers/UserMapper";

    const getUserInfos = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apiV4.get("/users/profile")
            .then((response) => {
                resolve(UserMapper.fromApiToAppObject({user: response.data}));
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error - getUserInfos: ", error);
                reject(error.response?.data?.title);
            });
    });
};
```

But when running, I get the following error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_.apiV4.get')
```

This happens on android and iOS.

Versions:

```
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react": "16.13.1",
"axios": "0.21.1",
```

I've tried to update the axios, but without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating the react native version from "0.63.4" to "0.67.5" (I chose this one because I already had other projects running the same version and the migration to the latest one was much more complex)

This was a very strong solution to a small problem and I don't think it's the right one, but it worked for me.

If you want to upgrade react native, don't forget to use the upgrade helper: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/